# What does it take to override a function in .NET

Tags: c#, overriding

I was asked this in an interview today and I just can't figure it out.  I was asked everything from beginning to advanced questions, but this one stuck out.  I was describing inheritance and polymorphism and then this question came up.  I have obviously never tried to override every method in a [C# / C++] class, but I wasn't aware there was something that was required in order to override a particular method (.ToString, for example).  Did I misinterpret the question or is there something required?  And if so, what forces this requirement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- the base class must not be `sealed`
- the method in the base class must be marked as `virtual` or `abstract`

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I think the interviewer was looking for.  I apologize for not getting back to you sooner.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are overriding must be declared as `virtual` or `abstract` (and be in a non-sealed type).  Otherwise, your only option is to *hide* it.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ and C#, you have to declare the base-class function as `virtual`.  Otherwise, a function in a derived class that has the same name and signature will hide the base class version.

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to make sense of this.  So [in C#] if I declare a base class as "virtual", you said that the derived class will have the same name and signature... but will it have the same "functionality".. i.e, will the derived class function's methods be the exact same?

Comment: You need to mark the base class *function* as virtual, not the class.  It will have the same functionality...unless you override the function in the derived class.

Answer (score 0):

The method that you want to override must be marked [virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or `abstract`.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand polymorphism and inheritance, then I feel like maybe you're overthinking the question. I mean C# override is simply like this:

```
  public override double parentFunction() 
  {
     //child implementation
  }
```

... and the parent function must be delcared as virtual.

Without hearing the question verbatim, it's hard to say what the interviewer was looking for. My experience with interviewers is that they're just looking to make sure you understand the generalities, but who knows. I'd be curious to find out if you get the job : )  Good luck!

Comment: Heh, I really appreciate your response and wish I could have gotten back to you earlier.  I was extremely stressed and he started with the hardest questions first so I wasn't comfortable and screwed up even the easiest questions.  But the job was a long-shot and I'm already employed, so no biggie.  Thanks again!